# How can I vertically align elements in a header without tables?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

It seems like vertical aligning in CSS is a common problem but I can't seem to work through this. I'm trying to create a basic header (recreating the Youtube video page for practice), and I can't get the search form and logo to vertically align within the header `div`.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/eternal/qp6cqtaj/

I tried to copy a solution I found that used pseudo-classes, but so far it didn't work.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EFkps0m.png"></img>
    <form>
       <input type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  min-width: 60px;
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 50px;
}

.header:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.centered * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header form {
  left: 25px;
  width: 65%;
  max-width: 583px;
  height: 50%;
}

.header input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I used to follow [this](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) to center things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of code writing and maintenance. Use a **[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EFkps0m.png">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center; /* this one line vertically centers all child elements */
    height: 50px;
}

.header > form {
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.header > form > input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp6cqtaj/5/

A few notes:

- With the flexbox you can achieve your goal with about 60% less code.
- The layout is responsive.
- It's easy to align the child elements horizontally or vertically with the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties.
- The `<img>` tag is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). No closing tag required. You can remove the `</img>`.

Comment: Great flexboxage _and_ good notes but with one glaring exception: [IE<11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: @Will, thanks for the feedback. And yes, IE10 provides partial support, and IE 8 and 9 provide no support. I don't code for IE 8 and 9. Maybe the OP doesn't care either. If he/she does, there are other options on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align to `.centered *`

```
.centered * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp6cqtaj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can simplify your HTML, no need for centered div:

```
<div class="header">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/EFkps0m.png"></img>
<form>
<input type="text">
</form>
</div>
```

And, since you already using fixed height:

```
 .header {
  min-width: 60px;
  width: auto !important;
 white-space: nowrap;
  height: 50px;

}

.header form {
  left: 25px;
  width: 65%;
  max-width: 583px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
      vertical-align: middle;
}

.header input {
  width: 100%;
}
.header img {
    display:inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/74bhq5bj/2/
line-height on form element helps, in this case.